# Can we generate auto variables with pre-determined names and assign them to results of a query in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, variables, count

I want to count the results of this query.

```
for example:
    i = count results{ SELECT SUM(TimevalueColumn) 
                  FROM InfoTable 
                  where TimeStampColumn between @FromAgivenDate and @ToAGivenDate
                  GROUP BY TimeStampColumn}
```

Then generate variables like this:

```
Generate auto variables like "var"+[1 to i]
```

If results are 3 we should have var1, var2, var3

Then I want to assign var1 to the result 1 of that query. var2 to result 2 and so on.

then I want sum the vars like this.

```
sum(vars[1 to i]) as total
```

then I want to do something with total.

Is there a way to implement **this** logic?

Comment: You should change your mind, stop thinking row by row or value by value and start thinking on sets. You can store the whole result into a table variable or a temporal table.

Comment: would you illustrate the thing you said with an example? It should open my mind I guess...

Comment: You can select into a temporal table `SELECT SUM(TimevalueColumn)  INTO #results  FROM InfoTable WHERE TimeStampColumn between @FromAgivenDate and @ToAGivenDate GROUP BY TimeStampColumn` then operate with #results temp table.

Comment: I dont get the INTO #results part. what is the `result` you are mentioning is it a sub query? and is it possible to say select sum `INTO` something?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of generating multiple auto-generated variables you can use the SUM function. In the following code `#InfoTable` is a temporary table. Instead of sum up the auto-generated variable, you can use the SUM function and get the result in a local variable (@SumOfTimevalueColumn)

```
CREATE TABLE #InfoTable (TimevalueColumn int)

INSERT INTO #InfoTable VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO #InfoTable VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO #InfoTable VALUES(3)

DECLARE  @SumOfTimevalueColumn int

SELECT @SumOfTimevalueColumn = SUM(TimevalueColumn)
FROM #InfoTable

SELECT @SumOfTimevalueColumn

DROP TABLE #InfoTable
```